# Partial derivative using chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative

Find $\frac{dz}{dt}$ -

$z(x,y) = x^2y^3$ , $x(t)= 2t^3$ $y(t)= 3t^2$

First , this is the chain rule formula I am using -

$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} . \frac{dx}{dt} +  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} . \frac{dy}{dt} $

I found that $  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2xy^3$ and $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 3x^2y^2$

I found that $\frac{dx}{dt}  = 6t^2$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = 6t$

Now when I substitute back into the formula, I don’t get the required answer of $1296t^{11}$ . Where did the $x$ and $y$ go ? Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: You're basically all the way there. Substitute the right hand side of the $x(t)$ equation to get turn your $x$ into $t$ and similarly for $y$. This should get you your answer.

Comment: I'm getting the correct answer... $\frac{dz}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} = 2xy^3\cdot6t^2 = 2\cdot2t^3\cdot27t^6\cdot6t^2 = 648t^2$, and similarly for the right hand side.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley Surely you mean $648t^{11}$. And then to that you add $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$ which should give the answer.

Comment: Whoops! Yep! Ha ha, it should be $648t^{11}$

Comment: I got it, thanks!!